# Network unlock a never-activated phone

Tags: sim-unlocking, carriers

I currently have a Motorola Moto G6 Play that was originally purchased 3 years ago from Virgin Mobile USA (which doesn't exist anymore), and was never activated. Interested in getting it network-unlocked, I called Boost Mobile (which acquired Virgin Mobile USA's assets), but was told to do that I'd first need to activate it for at least 12 months as per their contract.

Is there any way around that requirement? Does such a contractual requirement to activate a phone before network-unlocking it last in perpetuity, or does it expire at some point? It's pretty unclear what the helpline person was telling me in this regard.

Comment: Policy matters are unrelated to Android. For technical details regarding network lock see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217365/218526

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does carrier/network lock work? How is it implemented?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217283/how-does-carrier-network-lock-work-how-is-it-implemented)

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Where can I resolve such policy/legal details?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: No.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins sorry I don't know.