# How can I unlock a carrier locked Android phone?

Tags: samsung, rooting, sim-unlocking

Is there a way to unlock a Samsung phone locked to a carrier without contacting the carrier for its unlock code?

Comment: [How does carrier/network lock work? How is it implemented?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217365/218526)

Comment: thanks for sharing that! so does that mean flashing an unlocked firmware won’t work?

Comment: Bootloader unlock/custom firmware has no effect on a carrier/SIM lock.